# Computed property in dom-repeat doesn't work

Tags: polymer, dart-polymer, polymer-1.0

I try to use computed property in `dom-repeat` helper but it throws exception immediately after I click button (see code below, packages versions: `sdk: 0.12.2`, `polymer: 1.0.0-rc.5`, `polymer_interop: 1.0.0-rc.4+1`).  What might be wrong? When I replace `{{computedItems}}` with `{{items}}` everything works fine.

```
class Item extends JsProxy{
    @reflectable
    String a="aaa aaa";
    @reflectable
    String b="bbb bbb";
    Item(this.a, this.b);
}

@PolymerRegister('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {

    @Property(computed:"getItems(items.*)")
    List<Item> computedItems;

    @property
    List<Item> items = [];

    @property
    String inp = '';

    MainApp.created() : super.created();


    @reflectable
    List<Item> getItems(_) {
        return items;
    }

    @reflectable
    void onTap(Event ev, Map details) {
        add("items", new Item(inp, 'aa'));
        set("inp", "");
    }

}
```

and `html` file:

```
<dom-module id="main-app">
    <template>

        <paper-input value="{{inp}}"> </paper-input>
        <paper-button raised on-tap="onTap">add to list</paper-button>

        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{computedItems}}">
            <div style="color:red">
                <span>[[item.a]]</span>
                <span>[[item.b]]</span>
            </div>
        </template>

    </template>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Without trying I assume it's  `.*` in `items.*`. Try just `items`

Comment: I used wildcard because I want to observe changes in `Item` fields. Anyway I have changed to `items.*` to `items` and it still throws.

Comment: I'm just currently trying to reproduce and I too encountered that it doesn't recognize changes. I changed it to `items` and don't get the error message anymore. Is there a reason you use `computed`? At least in the minimal example in your question it wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I know it's not necessary here. This is just simple repro case. I need computed bindings or computed property for `dom-repeat` in my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
@PolymerRegister('app-element')
class AppElement extends PolymerElement {
  AppElement.created() : super.created();

  @property
  List<Item> computedItems;

  @property
  List<Item> items = [];

  @Observe('items.*')
  void computeItems([_, __]) {
    set('computedItems', items.toList());
    // .toList() creates a copy, otherwise Polymer wouldn't 
    // recognize it as a change

    // this works as well
    // set('computedItems', null);
    // set('computedItems', items);
  }

  @property int itemsChangeIndicator = 0;

  @property
  String inp = '';

  @reflectable
  List<Item> getItems(_) {
      return items;
  }

  @reflectable
  void tapHandler(dom.Event ev, Map details) {
    add("items", new Item(inp, 'aa'));
    set("inp", "");
  }
}
```

(I renamed `onTap` because this naming scheme easily collided with event stream getters in the element, like `onClick`)